# PHPExcel : documentation for common functions

Tags: function, documentation, phpexcel

I am trying to find if PHPExcel has any documentation for simple functions like "getActiveSheet" as I would prefer not to get my nose inside the library's code. I've search a whole day through the links related to "PHPExcel functions documentation" and apart from https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/phpexcel_library/1.7.4/manual.html and https://github.com/cystbear/PHPExcel/tree/master/Documentation.
There wasn't any documentation other than of simple functions as toArray() or "getActiveSheet()" .

My question is: does PHPExcel have any documentation for common functions related to manipulating the worksheet object like rangeToArray() or getHighestRow()? If it does, where can I find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Human-generated documentation for can always be found on the [PHPExcel wiki](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/wiki), and there are also the [API Docs](http://hitautodestruct.github.io/PHPExcelAPIDocs/packages/PHPExcel.html)

The former is included in the repository in the `Documentation` folder

The latter you can also generate yourself from the source using PHPDocumentor

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am searching for documentation on helper methods for active sheet like the methods on "Reading Spreadsheet Files" listed in your wiki link. I can't seem to find them anywhere

Comment: All the methods for the WorkSheet object are defined in the [API docs](http://hitautodestruct.github.io/PHPExcelAPIDocs/classes/PHPExcel_Worksheet.html)

Comment: Thanks alot! I wasn't very familiar with going through such vast documentation. If I may make a suggestion, i think the API docs would benefit from some sort of search.

Comment: API Docs are built using a standard PHP tool called PHPDocumentor, perhaps having a word with the author of that might persuade him to make the generated docs searchable